# Iterating through divs with same class name

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, bdd, page-object-gem

I have the following DOM:

```
<form id="slideshow">
  <div class="slideshow-item">
  <div class="slideshow-item">
  <div class="slideshow-item">
</form>
```

I need to iterate through all the divs in this form element, perform some action on each div and then come out once all the divs are done.

I defined my locator as:

```
divs(:slideShowRow, :xpath => "//div[@class='slideshow-item']")
```

and tried iterating as:

```
slideShowRow_elements.each do |e|
  uploadSlideShowImage = e.text_field_element(:xpath => "//input[@type='file']")
  execute_script("$(arguments[0]).show();", uploadSlideShowImage)
  uploadSlideShowImage.send_keys("//path/to/image_file")
  textSlideShowRow = e.text_field_element(:xpath => "//input[@placeholder='Overlay Text']")
  textSlideShowRow.send_keys("row_number_x")
end
```

**Issue:**

The problem I am facing here is that the action is being performed on only the first element and not on all the 3 elements.

So the loop is running thrice as there are 3 divs but the action is performed on the same first div element thrice instead of individual div element.

*PS: I am using Page Object with Ruby and selenium webdriver.*

Comment: That is the correct way to iterate through the elements. It would help to show what "//perform action" is actually doing.

Comment: But the problem I am facing here is that the action is being performed on only the first element and not on all the 3 elements.

So the loop is running thrice as there are 3 divs but the action is performed on the same first div element thrice instead of individual div element.

Comment: I added an `id` attribute to each of the divs being "1", "2", "3". When I ran `page.slideShowRow_elements.each { |e| p e.attribute('id') }` it correctly outputted "1", "2", "3". That proves that the iteration does work. If the code isn't doing what you expect, I would guess that either the `//perform action` is doing something wrong or the implementation of the web application is doing something. That's why I suggest sharing how you perform the action. On that note, an actual page that reproduces your problem would also help.

Comment: It could be a dynamic issue that requires a wait but it's hard to tell without the rest of the relevant code.

Comment: What is the action you are trying to perform?

Comment: Action is that in each row: I need to upload an image and then add some text. I was trying it as follows:

slideShowRow_elements.each do |e|
  uploadSlideShowImage = e.text_field_element(:xpath => "//input[@type='file']")
  execute_script("$(arguments[0]).show();", uploadSlideShowImage)
  uploadSlideShowImage.send_keys("//path/to/image_file")
  textSlideShowRow = e.text_field_element(:xpath => "//input[@placeholder='Overlay Text']")
  textSlideShowRow.send_keys("row_number_x")
end

but currently, this is running only on the first row three times and not on individual div row item.

Comment: @JustinKo can you please help here!

Answer (score 0):

The script is correctly iterating through the `slideShowRow_elements`. The problem is actually with how elements are being located within each `slideShowRow_element`.

For the line:

```
e.text_field_element(:xpath => "//input[@type='file']")
```

The XPath expression actually says to find a file field element *anywhere* on the page. As a result, the one in the first row will always be grabbed. The XPath expression needs to be told to only locate the file field *within* the current row. This is done by starting the XPath expression with a period:

```
e.text_field_element(:xpath => ".//input[@type='file']")
```

This change needs to be made for both XPath expressions used:

```
slideShowRow_elements.each do |e|
  uploadSlideShowImage = e.text_field_element(:xpath => ".//input[@type='file']")
  execute_script("$(arguments[0]).show();", uploadSlideShowImage) 
  uploadSlideShowImage.send_keys("//path/to/image_file")
  textSlideShowRow = e.text_field_element(:xpath => ".//input[@placeholder='Overlay Text']")
  textSlideShowRow.send_keys("row_number_x")
end
```

Note that for `uploadSlideShowImage`, you can also avoid the problem by not using XPath:

```
uploadSlideShowImage = e.file_field_element
```

Comment: I have a doubt here @Justin. when we are iterating via .each, that e has say the first div row element. Now, when I specify: e.text_field_element(:xpath => "//input[@type='file']") without a '.', shouldn't it just fetch the file input from the first element. Why does it mean that pick up from anywhere on the page? (or pick up always first in this case).  Isn't the loop sufficient enough for that?

Comment: I agree, it's not intuitive. However, that is just how XPath is defined/interpreted. Starting with `//` means to start looking at the document root where as `.` says to start looking from the context node. The [XPath documentation has some good examples](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev) - specifically "`//para` selects all the `para` descendants of the document root and thus selects all `para` elements in the same document as the context node".

Comment: If you apply that example to the original code, that means the original code, `e.text_field_element(:xpath => "//input[@type='file']")`, is actually saying find the first file field element that is in the same _document_ as the slide show row. Since it is looking for one in the same _document_, the first match is always the one in the first row.